# Starting application from background process

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys, shellexecute, process.start

I'm working a small WPF based program for launching applications through system wide hotkeys implemented using hooking. I'm implementing it in C# and Visual Studio 2010.

When I detect the specific keypress I use Process.Start(...) to run the application. This works fine while Visual Studio is active, placing the new application in the foreground with input focus, as I would expect. If my launcher is in the background (behind another active program), it still detects the key and starts the application correctly, in front of everything else.

The problem is, that when I run the launcher without Visual Studio active, and my launcher application isn't front, neither will applications it starts. They appear in front of the launcher but behind the active application.

I can see that other software, like AutoHotkey, is able to do hotkey launching with this behavior, but I fail to see what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**: Just figured out a solution to this issue that works in my development environment. I first register a global hotkey through the Windows API RegisterHotKey using the launcher main window handle. The key could be any, but should be one that normally doesn't exist physically, F24 in my case. Then, whenever I detect a keypress through the hooks that should launch an app, I first call keybd_event to 'fake' a keypress for the hotkey.

For WPF use:

```
keybd_event((byte)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(Key.F24),0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

For WinForms use:

```
keybd_event((byte)Keys.F24,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

This will bring enough focus to the launcher, so that Process.Start(...) makes the executed program get in front. It does not bring the launcher window to front, nor does it make the launcher accept inputs.

If Activate() is called on the main window after the keybd_event(), this will bring the main window to front and allow for keyboard input, just as if the user had task switched.

Comment: Try to make your launcher the active window before launching the application

Comment: have you tried finding main window of the process and posting a WM_ACTIVATE message?

Comment: @DjSol: Suggestions how I go about doing that? As I see it, only Windows can activate the application, it prohibits the applications from taking focus it self.

Comment: @EliAlgranti: I've just tried it, didn't make any difference.